# What are best practices to solve `All files/directories will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions` when building docker images on Windows?

Tags: docker, windows

When a docker image is built on a Windows host the following message is returned:

```
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows
Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x'
permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files 
and directories.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not currently possible to disable that warning, see discussions on [Issue 20397](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20397):

> That warning was added, because the Windows filesystem does not have
>   an option to mark a file as 'executable'. Building a linux image from
>   a Windows machine would therefore break the image if a file has to be
>   marked executable.
>
> For that reason, files are marked executable by default when building
>   from a windows client; the warning is there so that you are notified
>   of that, and (if needed), modify the Dockerfile to change/remove the
>   executable bit afterwards.

In a sense this also means it's practically impossible to actually solve the issue.

What maybe can help a bit is moving the error message from stderr to stdout, released in docker 17.04. See [Issue 29856](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29856).